# Rubbish Values (b'\x00\x00\x00 ... ') - UART of Arduino to RPi 3B

Tags: pi-3, serial, arduino, uart

I am getting b'\x00\x00\x00 ... ' together with the data I want. For example, my Arduino is writing 'hello raspberry' to RPi. At the RPi, it receives 'b'\x00\x00\x00 ... hello raspberry\r\n '. Why?

Here's my coding at RPi:

```
ser=serial.Serial(port='/dev/ttyS0', baudrate=9600, parity=serial.PARITY_NONE, stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_TWO, bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS)

while True:
    x = ser.readline()
    print(x)
```

Whereas at Arduino Mega:

```
void setup()
{
    Serial3.begin(9600);
}

void loop()
{
    Serial3.println("hello raspberry");
}
```

Comment: Please show the Arduino code. It's hard to see the mistake otherwise.

Comment: The Arduino IDE serial terminal may not show null bytes, so they may be there in both cases. How many stopbits is "WO"?  I'm not a python user, but a quick glance at the docs implies this is supposed to be an actual number (`ONE` in this case).

Comment: @goldilocks If the OP is using '/dev/ttyS0' it makes no difference, because this is fixed, and only affects sending. On recent Raspbian '/dev/serial0' should be used.

Comment: It's the same even after I change the parity to TWO. Actually, what's all parity about? Any good documentation / reference for me to read?

Comment: The code shown doesn't tell us much. I'll guess you're using pySerial? If so, it looks like the code you have shown was copied and pasted from somewhere. I don't see a definition for the value "STOPBITS_WO"... where did you get that? - do you define it somewhere? You've gotten good feedback in the Comments above. Suggest you incorporate that feedback, edit your question, read [pySerial docs](https://pyserial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pyserial_api.html?highlight=PARITY_NONE), [RS232 basics](https://www.lookrs232.com/rs232/waveforms.htm) and [parity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parity_bit)

Comment: @Seamus 7 , I thought 'import serial' obviously means that it's from pySerial? Oh, my keyboard alphabet 'T' is having some sensitivity problem. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: This may have nothing to do with your problem but **the mini UART only supports 1 start and 1 stop bit** and you should use `/dev/serial0` in all code. See [How-do-i-make-serial-work-on-the-raspberry-pi3](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/45571/8697) Unless you list your code who knows?

Comment: Consider debugging Arduino and RPi separately before you connect them together.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is poor in detail. We are currently having difficulty reading your mind, but making a few assumptions leads me to suggest this might help:

```
ser=serial.Serial(port='/dev/ttyS0', baudrate=9600, parity=serial.PARITY_NONE, stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE, bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS)
```

If it doesn't, please read the comments, read the referenced documents in the comments, and edit your question.

Comment: What else of detail you want?

Comment: Nothing if this fixes your problem. If it doesn't, please show us the Python code, and explain what the defaults are for the Arduino Mega: stop bits & parity.